# How to separate a text file into lists to search from?

Tags: python, list

Beginner here trying to understand lists!

I am trying to read from a file containing zip codes and the city + state that is related to said zip code. I have to separate each into it's own list. Each line of text is one zip code, one city, and one state. How would I go about separating each into a three separate lists then calling it from another function to search the newly created lists?

Example of the text file:

"00501,HOLTSVILLE,NY

00544,HOLTSVILLE,NY

00601,ADJUNTAS,PR

00602,AGUADA,PR"

I tried starting lists and throwing them in there but it would only read one line at a time, and then throw the entire line into the first list, then same for the second, third, and so on.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

you should open your file for reading and iterate over each line

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
list = []

for line in f:
    list.append(line.split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will append the data into different lists.

```
>>> my_file = open('try.txt', 'r+')
>>> list1, list2, list3 = [], [], []
>>> for line in text:
...     words = line.split(',')
...     list1.append(words[0])
...     list2.append(words[1])
...     list3.append(words[2])
... 
>>> print list1
['00501', '00544', '00601', '00602']
>>> print list2
['HOLTSVILLE', 'HOLTSVILLE', 'ADJUNTAS', 'AGUADA']
>>> print list3
['NY\n', 'NY\n', 'PR\n', 'PR\n']
```